# Connecting phpMyAdmin to MySQL Server on OSX Yosemtie

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem connecting phpMyAdmin to my local MySQL server.
The pertinent information is:

- OSX 10.10.4
- MySQL 5.6.26
- phpMyAdmin 3.4.3
- Apache 2.4.10
- PHP 5.5.24

When I attempt to log into phpMyAdmin, the  message `cannot connect to the MySQL server` is displayed. phpMyAdmin/setup/ was used to establish the user ID and password.

No error code is displayed. The MySQL server is started through the "system preference" MySQL app.

Comment: Can you connect to the MySQL server using `mysql -u user -p` from command line?

Comment: I figured out the problems. I looked up setting MySQL root password via terminal and got the path to the command mysqladmin and set the password. Then in phpmyadmin, I had to supply the path to swetkey.conf, which is noted in phpmyadmin/setup/ on the authentication screen. Once all this was done, everything worked. Thanks for your help.